# Google Maps API with Django is not displayed when trying to bring data from a txt

Tags: javascript, python, google-maps

I have the following problem. I have embedded a map using Google Maps' API. My intention is to bring some values from a .txt (cordenates), put them into a list, and then display them in the Map, with lines between each point.
I have no problem doing this if I put the values manually in the list. But when I try to get them from the .txt file, the map is not shown in my page (the place where it should be is blank). BUT if I check in the source code the Script, it doesn't appear to have any problem... each point is shown as it should inside of the Script.
This is a part from my View:

def base (request):

```
 analyze_results('testing')
 with open('data.txt') as f:
     for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        points.append(words[1]+','+words[3])
 return render_to_response('base.html', {'points': points, 'user_data': user_data})
```

points = []

If I manually asign the points list, and take away the

with open('data.txt') as f:

```
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        points.append(words[1]+','+words[3])
```

it works perfectly.

Do you know what may be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your question history to learn more about what you're doing, and it looks like you have to clean up your text data before passing it to Google Maps. What's happening is the LatLng is being created as:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(38.4397984,061.1720742)
```

Notice that there's a '0' before 61.1720742, this is giving me "unexpected number" error in Chrome when I test it. You need to remove that zero. Also, the coordinates are "South" and "West", so you need to add a minus sign "-" to conform to Google Maps' LatLng format.

P.S. you can try `strip('0')` to remove the 0, for example, `'061.172000'.strip('0')` -> '61.172'

Comment: you are right! I added the .strip('0') and now it works fine. thank you very much. 
how should I do to strip the first character? Because using strip('0') if I have something like 061.01 would't it be 61.1?
thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome! I don't know all the details, I only know a initial zero is used for octal (base 8) numbers. 061 = decimal 49. So most likely it's reading this as "49" then the decimal places .1720742 giving the unexpected number error.